# Why this basic java programme is not compiling

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am getting an error while compiling this programe:

```
class ArraysInMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[]={1,6,2,5,3,8,9,0,5};
        Add5(array);
        for(int y : array){
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
    public void Add5(int x[]){
        for(int counter=0; counter < x.length; counter++){
            x[counter]+=5;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following **ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method Add5(int[]) from the type ArraysInMethods
        at ArraysInMethods.main(ArraysInMethods.java:6)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there you go, make your `Add5` method static:

```
 public static void Add5(int x[]){
        for(int counter=0; counter < x.length; counter++){
            x[counter]+=5;
        }
    }
```

basically it means that only static methods can be called from within static methods and `main` method in Java is static.

EDIT:
Why do you have to do that? Because static members of class exist without instance of a class whether non-static members don't. If you'd call static method without creating an instance of a class (valid) that would try to call a non-static method it wouldn't work because non-static method doesn't exist without an instance of a class.

Comment: yes it worked thanks for your reply but why we have to use static over here ??

Comment: It's explained in the compiler error message, but I'll add explanation to my answer. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: yeah please explain it to me i will be very grateful to you. Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry! iam a newbie over here that was my first question. Iam was not aware about that button so clicked it by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods and variables are at class level and can be called with the reference of class name while non static methods are at object level and can be called using the object of the class.

There is 2 things you can do.

1. Change the method to static

   class ArraysInMethods {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int array[]={1,6,2,5,3,8,9,0,5};
       Add5(array);
       for(int y : array){
           System.out.println(y);
       }
   }
   public static void Add5(int x[]){
       for(int counter=0; counter < x.length; counter++){
           x[counter]+=5;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Make the object of the class and call the method of the class using the object.

   class ArraysInMethods {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int array[]={1,6,2,5,3,8,9,0,5};
       new ArraysInMethods().Add5(array);
       for(int y : array){
           System.out.println(y);
       }
   }
   public void Add5(int x[]){
       for(int counter=0; counter < x.length; counter++){
           x[counter]+=5;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

`static` method can call to `static` methods in java.

`Add5()` is not `static` method so compile time exception came.

```
 package com.org.test; class ArraysInMethods {  
     public static void main(String[] args) {  
         int array[]={1,6,2,5,3,8,9,0,5};  
         Add5(array);  
         for(int y : array){  
             System.out.println(y);  
         }   
     }  
     public static void Add5(int x[]){  
         for(int counter=0; counter < x.length; counter++){  

             x[counter]+=5;
         }
      }
 }
```